# WHERE clause inside CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Can i use **WHERE** clause inside a **CASE** statement as given below?

**CASE WHEN A=1 THEN B WHERE C=0 ELSE A END**

Comment: No you can do something as `CASE WHEN A=1 AND C=0`

Comment: No, you just repeeat the `when`.

Comment: It is unclear where you want to use this. Are you trying to filter your results (`WHERE` clause) with these conditions, or conditionally select columns?  You can use boolean logic rather than a `CASE` to do it in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: each row of data is evaluated against the first when, if that is true it stops, if false it goes to the next when, if that is true then it stops  now, if false it goes to the next when... until all when's are evaluated then it goes into 'else'. each when is sort of like a "where"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case try this

```
CASE WHEN (A=1 AND C=0) THEN B ELSE A END AS Field_Name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write

```
CASE WHEN A=1 AND C=0 THEN B ELSE A END;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Just use

```
CASE WHEN A=1 AND C=0 THEN B ELSE A END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
CASE WHEN A=1 THEN B WHEN B=1 THEN A ELSE C END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE A 
WHEN 1 THEN A 
WHEN 2 THEN B 
ELSE C END
```

[link](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html) to see more

Comment: THanks all for the suggestions.. :)